# ssrs reporting error in report preview: cannot create connection with datasource

Tags: reporting-services, datasource

I have a ssrs report which uses a shared dataset and a shared datasource. I can preview it without problems in my local workspace. Now I have copied the report to a remote computer where I modified the connection properties of the datasource. I cannot preview the report on this system, getting an error:

"error has occurred during report processing. execution error in the shared dataset. Cannot create a connection with datasource of shared dataset." (my translation, message is german)

I can create a connection to the server ("test connection" in datasource is successful) and access the data of the dataset in the query designer. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Did you mean that you deployed your report to a reportserver (= remote computer)?

Comment: No, I just copied the visual studio project and tried to preview the report on the remote computer.

Comment: Have you resolved this yet?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on the remote computer where the drivers are not installed or installed incorrectly.

I have had issues where the server is not set up but my pc is. As such my query designer worked but when published and run from the server it didn't.